# Can I control how facebook timeline displays my photos?

Tags: web, facebook, promotion

As a gallery represented photographer in a resort community, my gallery and I really use Facebook for promotion. I just turned on Timeline today, marked my recent work as "Featured" and was aghast at how Facebook "featured" it for me. Yeah, it is bigger, but they cropped the top and bottom off!

Here's what my shot looks like now:

[image: Facebook's Timeline cropped a featured photo]

Yeah, you can easily click it to see it all, but frankly, it looked better **not** featured. And when you click it, comments go to the gallery page, not my page, which is both good and bad but certainly surprising.

Is not clicking "Feature" my only option right now? I suspect so but am hoping otherwise, or would love a workaround.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can't. And if you can, they're likely to change the UI on you in a few months. You can work around this by putting big frames on your images so the format fits what Facebook wants.

Comment: Sadly the "Non-feature" aspect ratio is different than the "Feature" one. And yeah, they'll change it all soon anyhow, right?

Comment: PS: I didn't downvote on this one, but I can see why someone might. It's really more a web services thing, and is very facebook-specific. On the other hand, like the question about printing out proof sheets, it's within the realm of "things a professional photographer might need to do".

Comment: Oh, that's ok. It is a gray area for sure. I know that almost all my photographic promotion comes from FB. And if someone wants to down vote, that's fine. I'm sure not going to lose sleep over it!

Comment: I'm not sure if StackExchange has a site where this would be more appropriate. It doesn't fit here, for sure. It may fit on another SE site, however in all honesty the best place to ask would be Facebook itself.

Comment: Well, I asked here because other photography related tools questions are asked here. Photoshop, Lightroom, Facebook, all tools of my trade...

Comment: Well, in all fairness, one of those isn't **really** a photography related tool...its just a social networking web site that happens to allow photography to be uploaded to it. Calling it a photography tool is _really_ stretching it ("business" tool is valid, though.) Of all the available sites for displaying photography, I think Facebook would come in dead-last after the likes of 500px.com, 1x.com, Flickr.com, RedBubble.com, DeviantArt.com, etc. We don't really have the knowledge base here, either in our members or other topics, to even begin to offer a useful answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame they seem to have a rigid format, what happens if you want to feature a portrait? But the obvious solution to me is to work out the aspect ratio and prepare an image in each batch/album that fits that format.